# How to change JRE Libraries on Eclipse Maven Project?

Tags: maven-3, java-6

is anyone knows how to change the jre libraries on java dynamic web project(I am using Eclipse and Maven)? The case is this, when I first created the project on Eclipse Oxygen package M5 the **default jre was 1.6**, I changed the **Java Build Path(libraries) into 1.7/1.8**, however upon updating the project it always **returns to 1.6** and there is a red mark on the project folder. I already tried deleting the project and import it as **Existing Maven Project** and then update and clean but still nothing happens. This happens whenever I am creating a project without XML based configuration. I installed JDK 1.8.0 update 111, 121, and 131 and Apache Tomcat V7(XAMPP). On my brother's laptop everything works fine.

By the way, I also tried to replace **.m2** folder of my laptop by copying **.m2** folder from my brother's laptop.

**Any help is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), the Maven integration for Eclipse, which offers the import as *Existing Maven Project* option. m2e takes the version for the *JRE System Library* container from the configuration of the `maven-compiler-plugin`; this ensures that Eclipse and `mvn` behave consistently. Try changing the `<source>` and `<target>` [configuration options](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) of the `maven-compiler-plugin`, maybe followed by a *Maven* > *Update Project* to make sure m2e has sync’ed the changes to the `pom.xml` with the Eclipse buildpath.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Everything's okay now.

Comment: Great! Can you please mark the answer as correct, then. Thank you.